# Can't Access Traefik dashboard outside server

Tags: linux, docker, traefik, ubuntu-server

I am learning traefik and I am trying to connect to Ubuntu server hosted on a raspberry pi, Traefik is running on Docker. Currently I just want to access the dashboard, however am unable to access it outside my server but can ping it from inside the server itself,

This is how my **traefik.yml** file looks like

```
api:
  dashboard: true
  insecure:  true
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"                        
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
```

**docker-compose** file

```
services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    networks:
      - traefik
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    command:
       - "--api.insecure=true"
       - "--api.dashboard=true"
       - "--providers.docker"
       - "--log.level=DEBUG"
       - "--configFile=/home/ubuntu/traefik/traefik.yml"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/traefik.yml:/home/ubuntu/traefik/traefik.yml
      - $PWD/acme.json:/home/ubuntu/traefik/acme.json
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: unless-stopped
networks:
  traefik:
    external:
      name: traefik
```

I have docker network registered called **traefik**

```
NETWORK ID     NAME        DRIVER    SCOPE
...
ef66.......   traefik     bridge    local
```